# GSUITE users.delete and transfering data

Tags: google-admin-sdk

When I delete a user using the admin console, I have the possibility to transfer users data before deleting.
Using the Users.Delete api (in C# winforms application) I don't have this possibility.
Is there perhaps a way to perform a data-transfer using api's (before deleting the account) ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is a specific API for this, called [Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/)

- It features the method [Transfers:insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/transfers/insert)
- Use it specifying parameters of the [Transfers resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/transfers) - important is `newOwnerUserId` and `oldOwnerUserId`